# Typescript 4.9: Type 'NonNullable<K>' may represent a primitive value, which is not permitted as the right operand of the 'in' operator.(2638)

Tags: typescript, typeguards

Typescript 4.9 features some changes to how the `in` operator works.

In the code snippet below, how do I convince tsc that `id` is not a primitive value?

```js
export type KeyOrId =
  | {
      key: string;
    }
  | {
      id: string;
    };

export default function foo<K extends KeyOrId | null>(
  keyOrId: K,
) {
 
    if (!keyOrId) {
      return undefined;
    }

    // Type 'NonNullable<K>' may represent a primitive value, which is not permitted as the right operand of the 'in' operator.(2638)
    return 'id' in keyOrId;
}
```

I've tried a guard with `typeof keyOrId !== 'object'`. No dice.

[Playground example](https://tsplay.dev/WoAPlN)

Comment: [Maybe workaround](https://tsplay.dev/NVbPnN)

Comment: Lowkey might be a bug? I don't see how this would make sense at all. If `K` isn't nullable then it must be an object...

Comment: Relevant: https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/51007 -- they mention a workaround to add a type guard of "object" to it, but you are most likely right -- it is a bug

Comment: [Apparently this only applies to objects???](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=5.0.0-dev.20221111#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBDAnmYcDSxEHkoEkAmcAvAFBxwA+cA3mefQNaYBccAzjFAJYB2A5gG465AL50qtevS75WHbvyFSRQkqEiw4+YADMAhgFcANvB0GeAYxhcIPODogQAPGjigYwHvjbpMOApRwPMZGAHwAFHRM2Hiy6AA0JACUNGTCcFw6cOEAhNH++CmSUnBQwDAGUHbm2jq8wPhK9GLpmdlIKBBZ+bHERERwAEQQAEYAVsBWg0Xp5GUVVXAA5DJLGXY9BE2iJOnzldVeuvWNJCJAA)

Comment: Yeah this seems like a bug.  Partly what's going on in #51007, and also `NonNullable<K>` has recently changed to be `K & {}` which apparently is not "objectlike" enough... if it had stayed as `Exclude<K, null | undefined>` then it would still work.  Feels like a confluence of unfortunate things

Comment: @caTS that workaround results in the call sites that depend on `KeyOrId | null` reporting `Argument of type 'KeyOrId | null' is not assignable to parameter of type 'KeyOrId'.ts(2345)`

Comment: There are lots of possible workarounds and without use cases in the example it's not really possible to know what to suggest.  You could do [this](https://tsplay.dev/w2z74w), but does that work for you?  If not, please [edit] the question to show code examples that need to succeed in the face of the workaround.

Comment: This has been filed as a bug at [ms/TS#51501](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/51501), btw

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This line is causing the issue - `K extends KeyOrId | null` .

`K extends KeyOrId | null`  = `K extends KeyOrId`  |  `K extends null` .

The following should work -

```
export type KeyOrId =
  | {
      key: string;
    }
  | {
      id: string;
    };


export default function foo<K extends KeyOrId>(
  keyOrId: K | null,
) {
 
    if (!keyOrId) {
      return undefined;
    }

    return 'id' in keyOrId;
}
```

Comment: This appears to work as expected in https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=5.0.0-dev.20221115#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBDAnmYcDSxEHkoEkAmcAvAFBxwA+cA3mefQNaYBccAzjFAJYB2A5gG465AL50qtevS75WHbvyFSRQkiVCRYcfMABmAQwCuAG3i7DPAMYwuEHnF0QIAHjRxQMYD3xt0mHAQAfAAUdEzYeLLolHA8JsYANCQAlDRkwnBcunDBAIThAfipklJwUMAwhlD2Fjq6vMD4SvRiGeWV1XAA5DJdmfYFkXAA-HCDBAB0Mqzj+BPhQiJAA

Answer (score 3):

This was caused by a bug in TypeScript, reported at [microsoft/TypeScript#51501](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/51501) and has been fixed by [microsoft/TypeScript#51502](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/51502).   This will be probably be released with TypeScript 5.0.  Until then it is available at [the nightly `typescript@next` build](https://www.npmjs.com/package/typescript/v/next).

[Playground link to code, version 5.0.0-dev.20221122](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=5.0.0-dev.20221122#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBDAnmYcDSxEHkoEkAmcAvAFBxwA+cA3mefQNaYBccAzjFAJYB2A5gG465AL50qtevS75WHbvyFSRQkqEiw4+YADMAhgFcANvB0GeAYxhcIPODogQAPGjigYwHvjbpMOApRwPMZGAHwAFHRM2Hiy6AA0JACUNGTCcFw6cOEAhNH++CmSUnBQwDAGUHbm2jq8wPhK9GLpAPStcAAqyKgA5ABytv0hegBGRsAuob1wALZ6iKXAYGVsnvB6cCtcs1zWAG6o+3pGBsDxcADuABZcFtcZPjwQ8ChQuzAehHo+MNeo3D413gEDeei8cAgWT+fV4M1BwCgehg0AAdOEAEwANgAzAAOJLpMoVKpwXoyGa8OD5WJCERAA)